# callback series of animations, why does the last one jump?

Tags: jquery, animation, fadein

I'm trying to have a simple animated fadein. 3 sets of text one-by-one, which I'm happy with the current speed.

But on the final animation I have a button coming in which seems to look harsh when it comes in. I've tried playing with the timings but it still doesn't look much better.

```
var $one = $('.one');
var $two = $('.two');
var $three = $('.three');

var $button = $('.intro-text .btn');

$one.hide();
$two.hide();
$three.hide();
$button.hide();

setTimeout(function() {
    $one.fadeIn(1000, function() {
        $two.fadeIn(1100, function() {
            $three.fadeIn(1000, function() {
                $button.fadeIn(3000);
            });
        });
    });
}, 1000);
```

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/7dkt5a49/)

what is causing that harsh jump?

Comment: It's there isn't it?

Comment: Now it's *obviously* there, because you've made an edit.

Comment: I've retracted my close and down votes, because now the relevant code is included in the question and it's clear. You have an up vote.

Comment: Strange, all I did was take out an alert I left in by mistake. The code was there. Maybe the Jsfiddle caused an error until it loaded? I saw the code from the start – so not sure what happened there... But thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because you set the 0.2s transition for any state of the button. In order to get rid of this unwanted effect, don't set it in the normal state, i.e. remove `a,`:

```
a:hover,
a:focus,
a:active,
a.active {
  outline: none;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
```

Comment: Ahhh! the pitfalls of using templates! thanks!

Comment: @user Hah, welcome :)